# No se despliegan mensajes de obligatoriedad - SelectOneMenu required

Tags: jsf, java-ee, java-8

Tengo dos `selectOneMenu` anidados, uno de paises y otro de ciudades, estos cargan los datos de forma correcta y al seleccionar un país las ciudades se actualizan de forma correcta, el problema es que los dos `selectOneMenu` tienen el atributo `required` y `requiredMessage`, pero cuando no selecciono ninguno de los dos campos la aplicación no hace nada (que es correcto), pero tampoco muestra los mensajes de error. En alginos post lei que en el `tag` `<f:selectItem` el atributo `itemValue` debería ir con `"#{null}"` pero esto ya lo contiene.

el siguiente es el código

**ciudadSelector.xhtml**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es" 
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
    xmlns:jsf="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf">
    <body jsf:id="body">
        <ui:composition>
                <label jsf:for="codigoPais">Pais</label>
                <h:selectOneMenu id="codigoPais"  value="#{ciudadSelector.codigoPais}" required="true" requiredMessage="Debe seleccionar un pais">
                    <f:selectItem itemValue="#{null}" itemLabel="-- Seleccione un pais --" noSelectionOption="true"/>
                    <f:selectItems value="#{ciudadSelector.paises}" var="pais" itemValue="#{pais.codigo}" itemLabel="#{pais.nombre}" />
                    <f:ajax listener="#{ciudadSelector.onPaisChange}" render="codigoCiudad"></f:ajax>
                </h:selectOneMenu>
                <label jsf:for="codigoCiudad">Ciudad</label>
                <h:selectOneMenu id="codigoCiudad" value="#{ciudadSelector.codigoCiudad}" required="true" requiredMessage="Debe seleccionar una ciudad">
                    <f:selectItem itemValue="#{null}" itemLabel="-- Seleccione una ciudad --" noSelectionOption="true"/>
                    <f:selectItems value="#{ciudadSelector.ciudades}" var="ciudad" itemValue="#{ciudad.codigo}" itemLabel="#{ciudad.nombre}" />
                </h:selectOneMenu>
                <div>
                    <h:messages />
                </div>
        </ui:composition>   
    </body> 
</html>
```

**CiudadSelectorController**

```
@Named("ciudadSelector")
@ViewScoped
public class CiudadSelectorController implements Serializable{
    
    @Inject
    private CiudadService ciudadService;
    
    private Map<String, List<Ciudad>> mapCiudades;
    private List<Pais> paises;
    private List<Ciudad> ciudades;
    private String codigoPais;
    private String codigoCiudad;
    
    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        this.paises = this.ciudadService.obtenerListaPaises();
        this.mapCiudades = this.ciudadService.construirMapaCiudadesPorPais();
    }

    //getter y setters
    
    public void onPaisChange() {
        
        if(this.codigoPais != null && !"".equals(this.codigoPais)) {
            this.ciudades = this.mapCiudades.get(this.codigoPais);
        }else {
            this.ciudades = new ArrayList<>();
        }
    }
}
```

El componente `ciudadSelector.xhtml` lo incluyo en un `form` ubicado en `informes.xhtlm`

**informes.xhtml**

```
<html lang="es" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
    xmlns:jsf="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf">
<head jsf:id="head">
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<title></title>
</head>
<body jsf:id="body">
    <ui:composition template="../../WEB-INF/templates/layout.xhtml">
        <ui:define name="main">
            <form jsf:id="consulta">
                <div>
                    <ui:include src="../componentes/comun/ciudadSelector.xhtml" />
                </div>
                <div> 
                    <button type="submit" jsf:action="#{informe.obtenerInformeCiudad(ciudadSelector.codigoPais, ciudadSelector.codigoCiudad)}">
                        Consultar
                        <f:ajax execute="@form" render="informe" />
                    </button>
                </div>
            </form>
            <div>
                <h:messages />
            </div>
        </ui:define>
    </ui:composition>
</body>
</html>
```

Al hacer el summit del form se envia al InformesController los datos del pais y la ciudad seleccionada, esto lo hace bien cuando selecciono los dos datos, pero cuando no selecciono uno o ninguno no llega al método.

**InformesController**

```
@Named("informes")
@RequestScoped
public class informesController {
    @Inject
    private FacesContext facesContext;
    
    public String obtenerInformeCiudad(String codigoPais, String codigoCiudad) {
        FacesMessage m = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "ingresando al metodo", "registrando ingreso al método");
        facesContext.addMessage(null, m);
        return "";
    }   
}
```

El método `obtenerInformeCiudad` cuando se ejecuta (si se seleccionan los dos campos) tampoco muestra el mensaje enviado al `FacesMessage`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<f:ajax execute="@form" render="informe" />
...
<h:messages />
```

Le estás diciendo que solo actualice el componente *informe*(*), que no parece incluir el `<h:messages>`.

Incluye el id de *messages* en la lista de componentes a actualizar.

```
<f:ajax execute="@form" render="informe mensajes" />
...
<h:messages id="mensajes" />
```

---

(*) Por cierto, no veo ningún elemento con id *informe* en tu código. ¿Es correcto el código que has puesto? Normalmente si JSF se encuentra con IDs que no existen, falla durante el rendering inicial de la página.

Comment: Muchas gracias por su ayuda @SJuan76, realice el cambio que mencionas y funciono de forma correcta; el código si es correcto, dado que el problema lo tenia en los mensajes no vi la necesidad de incluir el tag correspondiente.